# Site Outreach/Promotion at FOCS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'll be at FOCS in Las Vegas. Others from here might be there too. Is there anything we can do to help promote the site ? A meetup ? booth with big cstheory sign :).

Comment: Las Vegas? Maybe get some showgirls to help with promotion.

Comment: I won't be there, but I'd suggest a poster with a few "best questions" in large print on it: representatives of (1) community wiki, (2) a reference request where a top expert swooped in and resolved the issue, and (3) an open problem such as an NP-reduction where answerers solved it on the spot.

Comment: and leave it at the reception desk ? not a bad idea. Maybe I'll post a question asking for nominations. And here's the question: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/457/nominations-for-publicity-poster-at-focs

Comment: I suggest that we also add a small list of some famous theorist who use the site (of course with their permissions) with a one line (positive) comment/opinion from them about the site (similar to books).

Comment: @Suresh, it might also be nice to meet up for dinner one night (this could be rather informally put together). I'll be in Las Vegas too, and I wouldn't want to miss meeting anyone who I've interacted with here because we're lost in the milling of the crowd!

Comment: @Aaron: Why don’t you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Daniel, sounds like a good idea. Anyone else planning to be at FOCS ?

Comment: @Suresh, sorry for reading this so late... I'll be at FOCS too.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to get current site users together for a photo?  Preferably in the FOCS hallway during one of the small breaks, so that lots of people see a big photo and wonder what it's about.  Also, then we have a big photo we can post...somewhere...

Or maybe even hold up a big sign in the photo that says "cstheory.stackexchange.com", and then people won't have to wonder.

It will probably help to try and include some of the big names on the site.

Comment: of the current users, I know of only one (Daniel Apon) who plans to be there. of course there will be others, but they don't lurk on meta.

Comment: We might have more participation at FCRC 2011.

Comment: I'll also be there.

Comment: I do plan to be at FCRC.