# Nominations for publicity poster at FOCS ?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Aaron Sterling had the [nice suggestion (in comments here)](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/453/site-outreach-promotion-at-focs) for site promotion at FOCS: his idea was:

> a poster with a few "best questions"
>   in large print on it: representatives
>   of
>
> 1. community wiki,
> 2. a reference request where a top expert swooped in and resolved the
>      issue, and
> 3. an open problem such as an NP-reduction where answerers solved it
>      on the spot

Any nominations ? One per answer, and specify which category: in each case, also pick an answer if none was accepted. If we can get some nominations within a week I can mock up a poster and stick it at the registration desk.

**Update:** Great suggestions all. Any thoughts on the best way to lay these out on a poster ? One idea would be to orient the poster in landscape mode and have three columns, with 1/2 questions/answers in each.

**Update 2:** For logistical reasons, I had to can the poster idea. but I thought I'd use a variant of what Joshua was suggesting, which was to use a single sheet for each question, with the question on the front and the answer on the back. I can generate a number of copies for different questions, and try to slip them into people's registration bags :).

[Here's an example](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/example.pdf) of what I'm thinking. Tell me what you think. AND SOON :)

**Update 3:** New version with only answer hints. Thoughts ?

**Update 4:** I'm in Las Vegas now, and successfully got a sheet inserted in each registration packet, as well as scattering copies of the sheets on registration desks. I hope this will encourage more people to visit.

Comment: An additional suggestion, while I'm at it.  There should be one example of an answer by a "name to conjure with," e.g., Noam Nisan's accepted answer to this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/314/evidence-that-ppad-is-hard/319#319

Comment: Here's an example of a situation where a big name (Noam Nissan) made a reference request which was answered by a littler name (myself): http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/317/internal-regret-in-online-convex-optimization/ . I suspect that Noam didn't find that paper himself because the words "internal regret" weren't in the abstract. I could answer it only because I went to grad school with the people who wrote it.

Comment: How about mentioning several unsolved technical questions, too?  Glancing at [highest voted questions](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), [unshuffling a string](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-hard-is-unshuffling-a-string) and the [product of many degree-1 polynomials](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/681/multiplying-n-polynomials-of-degree-1) are the most voted among unsolved non-community-wiki questions (and I like both questions very much).

Comment: another nice idea...I like both those questions myself..

Comment: I have just realized that it can be a little risky because they might be solved before the poster stating them as unsolved is used.  But hopefully it is not a big problem (it may be even better: “This question, written as unsolved on the poster, was solved just two days ago!”).

Comment: I'd suggest we add a category for questions that are really interesting and should be more well known.  If people like that idea, I'd nominate http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/871/relationship-between-symmetry-and-computational-intractability and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/can-we-decide-whether-a-permanent-has-a-unique-term, but they don't really fit any of the current categories.

Comment: Along the lines @Joshua suggested, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-gap-3sat-np-complete-even-for-3cnf-formulas-where-no-pair-of-variables-appears is a great question that deserves to be better known, and might interest FOCS regulars.

Comment: @Andras - but there's no answer.

Comment: @Suresh: that's why I suggested it in a comment, it would be an example of an open question (doesn't fit into your 3 categories).

Comment: ah ok. i get it.

Comment: @Suresh: Just saw your PDF. Very nice. I think maybe you should *not* have the answers. Maybe just a quick hint or something. This will make people actually come to cstheory looking for the answers. For example, for open problems you can mention that it is open. For yes/no questions, you could state the answer "yes" or "no" and ask the reader to visit cstheory for the full answer. (You can also mention who answered the question.) So for example, for Tsuyoshi's question about P, PH, etc., the answer would be "Yes," and it could say "answered by Scott Aaronson, Ravi Boppana and Joshua Grochow"

Comment: @Robin, that's a thought. I have mixed feelings though. What do others think ?

Comment: @Suresh, @Robin: I think I like Robin's suggestion but I'd maybe take it one step further.  Following Robin's example of Tsuyoshi's question, the answer would say "Yes, as answered by Scott Aaronson, Ravi Boppana, and Joshua Grochow.  Want to know why? Go to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/!"

Comment: @Suresh: Nice PDFs! I think at the bottom it should have *some* sort of tagline below the link to the site. Along the lines of "CSTheory StackExchange: a Q&A site for all things TCS".  I know this isn't as catchy as what people were looking for here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/463/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline.  But on an ad for a site that's not yet well-known, I think we want to be as direct as possible, so it's clear exactly what it is these posters are advertising, namely, a Q&A site for TCS.

Comment: I could do the 'questions answered. in theory' tag line

Comment: ok I'm warming up to the idea of withholding answers. let me do an update. One constraint that I've faced thus far is that the answers were far too long to to include in the pdf. but this way, maybe I can get around that.

Comment: One more thing. How about giving a partial answer to tantalize the reader ?

Comment: Shorter URLs: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/ -> http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2032 etc.

Comment: ok that's easy to fix.

Comment: Looking good, and intriguing...

Comment: added a big-list problem as well.

Comment: @Suresh: Looking good. I like your idea of partial answers. Another small suggestion: make the title "Question" instead of "Problem".  It fits better with "Answer" on the back (as opposed to, say, "Solution").  Also many of the examples aren't exactly problems per se, but they are all clearly questions.

Comment: @Joshua: will change accordingly.

Comment: @Suresh Great work. Looks really well.

Comment: Nice work on the teaser pack.  Hope to see lots of FOCS-inspired visitors!

Comment: I just wanted to thank Joshua, Aaron and others for helping out with this. I was told that many people would pull the little sheets out of their registration packets and start discussing the questions. So it was a success in that sense.

Answer (score 15):

I nominate [Problems that can be used to show polynomial time hardness results](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/problems-that-can-be-used-to-show-polynomial-time-hardness-results/). It's an interesting compilation and even a future reference for problems that people are ready to believe are hard.

Answer (score 11):

A very popular question in Category 1 is [Algorithms from the Book?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/189/algorithms-from-the-book)

It is a soft question with a long list of great examples (currently 67 answers). It is sure to bring some visitors for this list alone.

Comment: This question certainly attracted a lot of attention.  However, the quality of answers at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read or even http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/174/major-unsolved-problems-in-theoretical-computer-science seems higher to me.

Answer (score 8):

I also like the question on [Max cut with negative edge weights](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/max-cut-with-negative-weight-edges), which is a very accessible question with a quite subtle reduction given by Peter Shor.

Answer (score 6):

I think Laurent Bienvenu's answer to “[Truly random number generator: Turing computable?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/truly-random-number-generator-turing-computable)” is one of the best examples of category 2 on the site.  (Silly request: if you end up using it, perhaps you could edit out his reference to my name.  I almost didn't nominate it for that reason, but decided I had to, because the answer was so good.)

Comment: I added the title of the question you linked to.  I hope you do not mind.

Comment: I second this nomination.  I was delighted to receive such a detailed and knowledgeable answer!

Answer (score 6):

For Category Three, I'd like to nominate the [Magic is Turing Complete](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/is-magic-the-gathering-turing-complete) question.  It's a little (by which I mean *very*) dorky, but reading it made me smile and smile, because of how enthusiastic everyone was.

Plus, extra points for the poster title "Magic is Turing Complete." :-)

Comment: +1. Very dorky, but very awesome nonetheless. (I don't know anything about MTG, but it looks really complex from the discussion.)

Comment: If you use this question, I recommend importing the newer, cleaner solution from Take3Cards.

Comment: As I commented to the question, the question is not about the Turing completeness of the game in the usual sense.  I find the title of the question rather misleading.

Comment: @JeffE: where is the new clean soln ?

Comment: @Suresh: http://draw3cards.com/questions/2851/is-magic-turing-complete/2866#2866

Answer (score 6):

For the converse of category 2 (that is, asked by an expert, answered by a graduate student): Ryan Williams' [Which interesting theorems in TCS rely on the Axiom of Choice?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/which-interesting-theorems-in-tcs-rely-on-the-axiom-of-choice-or-alternatively), or maybe just the core question:

> What is the most striking example in TCS that you know where [the axiom of choice is] required?

With [Janne Korhonen's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/which-interesting-theorems-in-tcs-rely-on-the-axiom-of-choice-or-alternatively/1941#1941).

Comment: This was a really nice example.

Answer (score 6):

A category 1 (community wiki) example with great, non-obvious answers is ["Examples of the price of abstraction?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/608/examples-of-the-price-of-abstraction)

This question also has a title that is intriguing.  This might motivate people to look at the page just to find out what it is about.  A shorter link: http://tinyurl.com/price-abstraction or [Examples of the price of abstraction?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/608)

Answer (score 5):

I nominate Tsuyoshi's [A decision problem which is not known to be in PH but will be in P if P=NP](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/a-decision-problem-which-is-not-known-to-be-in-ph-but-will-be-in-p-if-pnp).  The problem can be stated **very** concisely, as is needed since you wont have much space on a poster. Moreover, the question looks easy at first sight, but isn't really, making the reader start thinking on this. Whether or not the reader solves the problem, he/she will feel curious to know what the posted answers are and will come here to read the answers.

This probably falls in category 2, but it wasn't really a ref request.

Comment: Thanks for nomination.  Honestly speaking, this is a little embarrassing because the question as is stated turned out to be very easy if you think about it in the right way….  But because many people seem to like the question (which I am happy about), I do not mind if the question is put on a poster.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: But MANY hard things are easy if you "just" think about them the right way!

Comment: @Daniel: Fair enough.  In fact, it may be arrogant of me to wish that my question had been harder than it turned out to be.  At least I am happy that I received three answers from each of which I learned a new thing, and also I am happy that some people liked both the question and the answers.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Aaronson's [Circuit lower bounds over arbitrary sets of gates](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/circuit-lower-bounds-over-arbitrary-sets-of-gates).  Unfortunately both the question and the [accepted] answer are probably too long to play well on a poster.  Maybe just the first two paragraphs (+ the next sentence) of the question, and some excerpt from the answer, though I'm having difficulty deciding what to excerpt.  Maybe @András Salamon would like to provide a shorter version more suitable for a poster?

Comment: I'd be happy to compress Scott's question and the answers for a poster, if this is seen as suitable (it might be a bit too specialized).  It certainly qualifies as useful for me personally -- trying to answer the question helped me to turn a few fragments into a more solid understanding.

Comment: andras, can you do the compression (see the format I proposed in the latest update)

Comment: @Suresh: Hope the version I emailed you is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

A category 3 example is David Eppstein's question about [Positive topological ordering](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/positive-topological-ordering).  This was not only solved (19 days later), but generated a lot of interesting discussion and at least two follow-up questions by other people:

- [Positive topological ordering, take 2](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/positive-topological-ordering-take-2)
- [Positive topological ordering, take 3](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/positive-topological-ordering-take-3)

Answer (score 4):

I really like the [Multiplicative Version of 3SUM](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/multiplicative-version-of-3-sum) question: given a set of numbers, are there numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ in the set such that $ab=c$? It is very easy to understand, and just ever-so-slightly different from the infamous 3SUM problem that many know already.

Answer (score 3):

Another question in category 2 is this one: [Does the trace norm of the difference of two density matrices being one imply these two density matrices can be simultaneously diagonalizable?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/does-the-trace-norm-of-the-difference-of-two-density-matrices-being-one-imply-the)

Unfortunately it is not something that a general TCS person cares about (or understands). But it was answered by a top expert in the field, and indeed the OP mentioned that the OP had learnt the material after reading the same expert's lecture notes on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Collecting together some of the comments suggesting open questions (including those by Tsuyoshi and Joshua):

- [How hard is unshuffling a string?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-hard-is-unshuffling-a-string)
- [Is Gap-3SAT NP-complete even for 3CNF formulas where no pair of variables appears in significantly more clauses than the average?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/is-gap-3sat-np-complete-even-for-3cnf-formulas-where-no-pair-of-variables-appears)
- [Can we decide whether a permanent has a unique term?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/can-we-decide-whether-a-permanent-has-a-unique-term)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the layout of such a poster: I actually prefer ad campaigns consisting of several small posters, each in the same style but with different contents. Each time you see a new poster you think how clever it is, rather than just thinking "Oh, there's that same poster again that I've seen 5 times already."

I don't know if this is feasible or not given the physical layout of FOCS, since there's probably only one registration table and not really other opportunities to put up flyers.  But even if you just have one pile of flyers spread out a little so people can see that there are in fact several distinct ones, that could work.

If so, then I'd suggest one question per page.  The question big and bold, near the top (maybe use landscape layout), and the answer(s) in smaller text--probably necessary because the answer's tend to be longer--maybe with the most exciting/relevant part of the answer also in bold.

Oh, and of course, "cstheory.stackexchange.com" (perhaps plus a [tag line](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline), which doesn't have to be the same on each page) at the bottom.  Doesn't have to be too large: once you hook 'em with the interesting Q&A, hopefully they'll be interested enough to find out what the flyer is about, regardless of how large or spiffy the URL is.

Comment: that's an interesting idea. so then make a number of these and even just tile them ? btw I have approval from the local organizers for a display

Comment: +1: Great idea. Some people will be motivated to go around looking for all the posters to make sure they read all the questions. This might even generate discussion among the participants during coffee breaks.

Answer (score 2):

An example from Category 3: [Is it NP-hard to play international draughts correctly?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/is-it-np-hard-to-play-international-draughts-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

If this question will end up having a nice collection of the best questions from the site, then I recommend this question in category 1 (or 0).

Comment: I like the idea of self-reference :), but seriously, I do not think that it works because it is a meta question.  Advertising that there are interesting questions _about_ the website will not make people visit the website.

Comment: I thought that we would also include the answers, which would hopefully be a perfect summary of the best questions.

Comment: I am not sure about that.  I do not know the supposed size of the poster, but I was thinking of a letter-size paper, which is clearly too small to include any answers.